# How can I redirect based on page in Woocommerce?

Tags: redirect, woocommerce

Normally, the "customer" is redirected to the "my account page" after logging in. However, I want to change it to Homepage. I wrote a role-based code for this. However, as far as I can see, if the customer logs in on the payment page, they are redirected to the Homepage. To prevent this, I made a check with is_checkout. But this time my code is not working at all. I've searched for a solution to this but couldn't find an answer.
I can't see an error in the code. However, I couldn't understand why it wasn't working.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_customer', 99, 2 ); 
    function wc_custom_redirect_customer( $redirect, $user ) {
      //Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
      $role = $user->roles[0];
      if( $role == 'customer' && !is_checkout()):
        //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
        $redirect = home_url();
      endif;
      return $redirect;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *is_checkout()* function returns false, because the *woocommerce_login_redirect* triggers on the authorization page. If you want to redirect users based on the last visited page, you need to store its slug, path, or ID as a cookie.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in the function.php file. I tried many ways but couldn't find a solution.